# Loading GLUquadric objects as a text file into opengl windows form

Tags: winforms, opengl, managed-c++, glu

I have Created an OpenGL view on a Windows Form as on [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16051/Creating-an-OpenGL-view-on-a-Windows-Form) and successfully embedded opengl into visual c++ windows form.Accordingly I have 2 files - rendering.h and opengl.h

Here's my original code....

Well then I extended my "OpenGL View on Windows Form" and combined it with NeHe's Tutorial "LESSON 27 - SHADOWS" and brought the code without errors. But still I have an obstacle!

Link error:

1> Generating Code...

1>PhotoRealisticRendering.obj : warning LNK4248: unresolved typeref token (0100002F) for 'GLUquadric'; image may not run

1>OpenGL.obj : warning LNK4248: unresolved typeref token (0100001B) for 'GLUquadric'; image may not run

Below are other 2 important files - shadow.h and 3Dobject.h

Answer (score 2):

You're confusing GLUT with OpenGL. GLUT is a simplicistic application framework for creating a window and simple user interaction. You're not required to use GLUT at all.

You're using Windows Forms, which means, *that* is your framework. Using GLUT makes no sense then. You have to use the input event handling methods of Windows Forms. Here's an article on how to do it on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171538(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1

Comment: Thankyou sir! Your answer is helpful...I'll try implementing  input event handling methods of Windows Forms.

Comment: Thankyou sir! keyboard event is working when i tried input event handling of Windows form!

Comment: Sir! But Iam completely puzzled about how to represent arrow keys(UP ARROW, DOWN ARROW, RIGHT ARROW, LEFT ARROW). For other alphabetic keys i just used.... if(e->KeyChar=='D')...

Comment: Keyboard event problem is finally solved! Thank you sir!

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: looking at the code you provided, it seems there's no relation between the keys array and your ProcessKeyboard callback. See for instance [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340159/longish-delay-between-two-consecutive-keydown-events).

(Original post snipped out, as not a good advice in this context, as stated by datenwolf)

-- Providing an excerpt of your source code always help to clarify/answer questions

Comment: GLUT and other frameworks (like Windows Forms) don't mix. You can't use GLUT from within another framework. Your "advice" only adds confusion.

Comment: Through it's a bit hard to determine which framework was actually used by the OP in the end, I completely agree with you.

Comment: He's using Windows Forms. Just look at the tutorial OP linked (Windows Forms in Managed C++) and OP is mentioning it explicitly.

Comment: Yes, but OP is probably also using glutSolidTeapot to generate a mesh to display. However, it's not possible to hook a keyboard func with glutKeyboardFunc if no window was created with glutCreateWindow, so as previously stated, I completely agree with you :) EDIT: posted the comment before I saw the edit, but my original comment makes sense.

Comment: keyboard event problem is finally solved . Thankyou sir!